# Connecting to remote cassandra database

Tags: cassandra, dbeaver

I am trying to connect to a remote cassandra database using dbeaver.
I installed cassandra over an ubuntu machine from digital ocean, and I am running the dbeaver from my local machine.
When I leave the default `/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml` file, and then run the `netstat -ntlp | grep 9420` I find that the connection is on and waiting for connection but once I update both the `listen_address` and the `rpc_address` to the public IP address of the remote machine, I found that I am no longer able to connect even locally to the database, using cqlsh cli.

What are the steps I should do to connect to a remote cassandra database, I read a lot of articles, but obviously there is something missing I can't understand

Comment: Public IP - do you mean your Cassandra database is exposed in internet?. update the question with your cqlsh error.

Comment: Can you share the command you're running to start cqlsh? After setting the public IP, you might need to use cqlsh <hostname>

Comment: I found the mistake, it was in my understanding to cassandra connection, when I updated the rpc_address (which means the public ip address of the node iteself) and left the listen_address (address of other nodes in the cluster), I can now connect to the database remotely, Thanks so much